# SilverStripe 3.1: Only display dataobjects with a current or future date

Tags: php, date, silverstripe

I have dates for a show. A short list of these is displayed on the home page. How do I code it to only show current and future show dates ignoring past dates?

I found this example but so far its not working so I may not be applying it correctly. https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/data-model-questions/show/14451
Or is there a way to do it in the template?

HomePage.ss

```
<% loop $Projects.limit(1) %>
<% loop $Entrys.limit(10) %>
    <li class="tourdate"><strong>$EntryDate.ShortMonth 
      $EntryDate.DayOfMonth</strong> - $Location</li>
<% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

ProjectPage.php

```
private static $has_many = array(
               'Entrys' => 'Entry'
           );
```

Entry.php which are dated

```
'EntryDate' => ‘Date'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`EntryDate.InPast()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/en/3.6/class-Date.html#_InPast), like so:

```
<% loop $Projects.limit(1) %>
    <% loop $Entrys.limit(10) %>
        <% if not EntryDate.InPast() %>
            <li class="tourdate"><strong>$EntryDate.ShortMonth 
                $EntryDate.DayOfMonth</strong> - $Location
            </li>
        <% en_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

I haven't tested this specific example so you may need to tweak it slightly.

Also, I'd prefer to have this sort of logic handled at the Class level with a method like `getUpcomingShows()` that would return a number of objects (dynamic or static limit) which have their dates on or after now.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a special method, such as `getUpcomingShows`, because you can solve the issue with a simple DB query, which is more performant. The above approach might also render less than 10 items, even if there are more in the DB (depending on how `$Entrys` are sorted by default)

Comment: I'm running into an issue with this which is probably due to not using getUpcomingShows. Currently like @bummzack suggested it shows less than 10. The limit means it counts 10 and if only 9 and 10 are in the future it shows 2. Even if there are 100 entries. As its only counting the first 10. The correct result should be it shows 10 upcoming shows from todays date. Help turning this into a class would be great!? thanks

Comment: @pinkp Could you make post an example of how you're fetching the upcoming shows? I think your issue is due to filtering order. You're probably getting 10 items then checking if they are in the future, you should instead get all the items that are in the future, and then limit 10, something like:

`$this->Entrys()->filter(['EntryDate:greaterThan' => date('yyyy-MM-dd')])->limit(10)` at the `ProductPage` scope. (also, sorry for the overly shrunk code, it seems code blocks are not allowed on comments)